# Detect when user exits a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

how can I detect when user leaves/exits a fragment? I tried using `onStop()` but it also gets called when I am in the app switcher or leave the app.

I'm using kotlin for android

Comment: use `onDetach()` - `onDestroy()` or `onDestroyView` instead. `onStop()` is called when screen is just hidden like when another fragments becomes visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use onDestroyView() or onDetach()

**onDestroyView()**

Called when the view hierarchy associated with the fragment is being removed.

**onDetach()**

```
Called when the fragment is being disassociated from the activity.
```

or more details. [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)